# Fetch mysql rows into a table according to subject type

Tags: php, mysql

Here is a sample of my table (reformatted for clarity)

```
  Subject   Percentage  Grade
  English     40%       D
  Chemistry   80%       A
  Physics     50%       C
```

So, basically i want to fetch this data and represent it this way:

```
  English   Chemistry    Physics
  40%           80%        50%
  D              A          C
```

How do i go about it? 
Thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: select subject,percentage(if(subject="English",1,0)) as "English",sum(if(subject="Chemistry",1,0)) as "Chemistry",sum(if(subject="Physics",1,0)) as "Physics" from exam_records group by percentage

Comment: You want to fetch all the results from your table?  I don't understand the sums in your query.  What conditions do you want to return data for?

Comment: This is a pivot table query. It's a very frequently asked question.

Comment: @dmikester1 i am not sure whether i am doing the right thing in my query thats why i need help. I want to convert the table rows to be like columns some how.

Comment: or just rotate your monitor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
    select english , chemistry , physics from (


    select (select percentage from Table1 where subject = 'English' ) as english,
           (select percentage from Table1 where subject = 'Chemistry') as chemistry,
           (select percentage from Table1 where subject = 'Physics') as physics

    from Table1 group by english
    union all

    select (select Grade from Table1 where subject = 'English' ) as english,
           (select Grade from Table1 where subject = 'Chemistry') as chemistry,
           (select Grade from Table1 where subject = 'Physics') as physics

    from Table1 group by english
     ) t
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
 ENGLISH    CHEMISTRY   PHYSICS
  40%          80%        50%
   D            A          C
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b85f/32)

Comment: @DreamEater thanks so much guys. This is really of great help. Again, thanks so much, it has helped me great.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Have got a question about this. This works very fine for one record, but when i have many records in the database, it returns a "Subquery returns more than 1 row" error. Please help me.

Comment: i dont know how you have many records , but can you edit my fiddle demo and add your records? and i will try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

fetch data into array and then loop through array to populate table rows

```
$subject = array();
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
{
    $subjecta = $row[0]; 
    $marks =  $row[1];
    $grade =  $row[2];
    array_push($subject,$subjecta)
    $subject[$marks] = $grade ;
    $subject[$grade] = $marks ;

}
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($subject as $sts) 
{ 
echo "<th bgcolor='#BEBEBE'>$sts</th>"; 
}
echo "</tr>";
```